# Como se cria voids que mudam o valor de uma variável sem IF? (como métodos em Python)

Tags: c#, python, bubblesort

Para simplificar a minha pergunta, irei mostrar o Bubble Sort em python:

```py
def bubbleSort(self):
    for i in range(len(self) - 1):
        for j in range(len(self) - 1):
            if self[j] > self[j+1]:
                self[j], self[j+1] = self[j+1], self[j]

l = [2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1]

bubbleSort(l)

print(l)
```

SAIDA:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Eu criei um código no C#:

```cs
using System;

public class ListFunction : Object
{
    public static int len(var l)
    {
        int len = 0;
        foreach (var i in l)
        {
            len++;
        }
        return len;
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] l)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len(l); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < len(l); j++)
            {
                if (l[j] > l[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = l[j];
                    l[j] = l[j + 1];
                    l[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var l = new List { 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1 };

bubbleSort(l);
```

Eu não testei, pois tinha erro. Erro não deixa testar, certo?

Comment: Você está usando `var` em tudo lembre-se que [tag:c#] é uma [linguagem fortemente tipada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_tipada) e que parâmetros devem ter o seu tipo explicitamente declarado. A linguagem não aceita processamento de dados fora da declaração de classe e controle de fluxo fora de métodos.

Comment: Ahh, Entendi. Pode me mostrar como se cria esse tipo de função?

Comment: Tem muitos erros  no seu código não vou perder o meu sábado os corrigindo. Exemplo a funcão `bubbleSort()` não retorna um valor, não possui tipo de retorno e na falta deste não possui um atributo de saída de parâmetro, a função `len()` não deveria existir,......

Comment: Ok. Mas eu também queria saber como se vê o tamanho de uma lista

Comment: [`List<T>.Count`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=net-5.0). Exemplo: `var l = new List<int> { 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1 };  Console.WriteLine(l.Count);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olha só, não vou detalhar todos os erros, até porque são muitos para escrever um ou dois parágrafos a respeito de todos eles, então aqui estão apenas algumas observações:

```
public class ListFunction : Object
```

Não precisa extender Object manualmente, toda classe estende Object.

```
public static int len(var l)
```

Você precisa definir o tipo de variável que você irá receber aqui, C# apenas infere o tipo da variável se ela for inicializada na mesma linha.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] l)
```

Você quer ordenar um array ou uma lista? Porque aqui você está declarando que você recebe um array, mas em seguida você invoca essa função passando uma lista.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len(l); i++)
```

Não deveria ser `len(l) - 1`, assim como no se código em Python?

```
for (int j = 0; i < len(l); j++)
```

Não deveria ser `j` ao invés de `i`?

```
var l = new List { 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1 };
```

Você não está passando o tipo da lista para o construtor, deveria ser `List<int>`, além disso você não adicionou o namespace da `List` no seu escopo.

```
bubbleSort(l);
```

Se `bubbleSort` é um método da classe `ListFunction`, então você precisa chama-lo como `ListFunction.bubbleSort(l)`

---

Como deveria ser:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var l = new List<int> { 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1 };
        BubbleSort(l);
    }
    
    public static void BubbleSort(List<int> l)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count -1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < l.Count -1; j++)
            {
                if (l[j] > l[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = l[j];
                    l[j] = l[j + 1];
                    l[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Agora um exemplo de função que ordena qualquer tipo de lista e qualquer tipo de valor:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var l = new List<int> { 2, 8, 3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 1 };
        BubbleSort(l);
    }
    
    public static void BubbleSort<T>(IList<T> l)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count -1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < l.Count -1; j++)
            {
                if (Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(l[j], l[j + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    T temp = l[j];
                    l[j] = l[j + 1];
                    l[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu não sabia que o tipo `System.Array` extende a interface `System.Collection.Generic.IList<T>`. Ah, e poderia colocar o keyword `ref` no l.

Comment: Eu era um noob no dia que eu postei a pergunta.